# How to describe when an extended method returns this?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

I have a method that returns `this`. How do I document it so that it gets the correct type even in subclasses?

If I do this:

```
class X {
  /** @return X */
  method () {
    return this
  }
}

class Y extends X {
  /** @type boolean */
  test = true
}
```

Then here:

```
new Y().method().test
```

`method` is described as an instance of `X`, not `Y`, so it doesn't hve the `test` property.

It should looks like

```js
class X {
  /** @return {this} */ // <------ this
  method () {
    return this
  }
}

class Y extends X {
  /** @type boolean */
  test = true
}
```

or

```js
class X {
  /** @return X */
  method () {
    return this
  }
}

/** @typedef {function():Y} Y.method */ // <------ this
class Y extends X {
  /** @type boolean */
  test = true
}
```

(I use the latest WebStorm if it's relevant.)

Comment: Not really sure what you are trying to achieve? Y is also invalid syntax in ES6

Comment: @Pavlo - True, it relies on the [class fields proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields), currently at Stage 3. Might make ES2019, if not probably ES2020.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder wow it's still in stage 3? Kinda weird that Chrome already supports it then...

Comment: @PatrickRoberts - My Chrome v69.0.3497.100 doesn't support public class fields syntax yet; I just updated this morning. What version are you using? (`class`, of course, was ES2015.) Mind you, one of the points of Stage 3 is that it's where implementations (like V8 in Chrome) start implementing the feature...

Comment: Mike, I've edited your question. I'm fairly certain I understood what you were asking, but if I've got it wrong, please edit to clarify.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder same version. I ran the code snippet above without errors (and even confirmed that the construction of `Y` returned an instance with `test: true`)

Comment: @PatrickRoberts - Strange. You're not transpiling by accident or something? [This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v21m5b0a/) doesn't work for me, for instance.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks a lot, you absolutely understand me right.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - running chrome (Mac) 71.0.3573.0 (Official Build) dev (64-bit) and fiddle does not work for me either.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder u can change 
`test = true`
to
`constructor () {
  this.test = true
}`

Comment: Running `Google Chrome 69.0.3497.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)
Revision 8920e690dd011895672947112477d10d5c8afb09-refs/branch-heads/3497@{#948}
OS Mac OS X
JavaScript V8 6.9.427.23` and it works for me. No transpilation, just executing in the JavaScript console. The fiddle works for me as well.

Comment: NOTE: WebStorm does transpile on the fly depending on configuration. That likely is the case here.

Comment: my version (69.0.3497.100) does not support class fields

Comment: @PatrickRoberts - Are you using any special runtime flags? Anyway, as I say, Stage 3 is when support is supposed to get added, often initially behind a flag. (Just a few days ago I had reason to wonder if Chrome supported this yet and was mildly surprised to find it didn't [at least, for me].)

Comment: @Mike - can you confirm your WebStorm config settings for file watchers and babel?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Ah, I do have `chrome://flags#enable-javascript-harmony` enabled. That's probably it.

Comment: @Randy Casburn - I do not use babel or some else, I only created index.js and opened it in WebStorm

Comment: @PatrickRoberts - Ah......... Yes, that's it. If I turn that on, I get them too.

Comment: I'm pretty sure its `@return {this}`, is there some reason you believe it's not?